# Cannot convert value of type 'FriendTableViewCell.Type' to expected argument type 'FriendTableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I'm trying to set up a friends list for my app and I am running into an error where I am being told that the compile cannot convert value of type 'FriendTableViewCell.Type' to expected argument type 'FriendTableViewCell'. This confuses me because its seemingly the same. Maybe I am missing something?

The Code I am having an issue with is:

```
@IBAction func followButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if let canFollow = canFollow, canFollow == true {
        delegate?.cell(cell: FriendTableViewCell, didSelectFollowUser: PFUser)
        self.canFollow = false
    } else {
        delegate?.cell(cell: FriendTableViewCell, didSelectUnfollowUser: PFUser)
        self.canFollow = true
    }
}
```

My Full Code is:

```
import Foundation

protocol FriendTableViewCellDelegate: class{
    func cell(cell: FriendTableViewCell, didSelectFollowUser user: PFUser)
    func cell(cell: FriendTableViewCell, didSelectUnfollowUser user: PFUser)
}




class FriendTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var friendName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var followButton: UIButton!

 weak var delegate: FriendTableViewCellDelegate?


var user: PFUser? {
    didSet {
        friendName.text = user?.username
    }
}

var canFollow: Bool? = true {
    didSet {

        if let canFollow = canFollow {
            followButton.isSelected = !canFollow
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func followButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if let canFollow = canFollow, canFollow == true {
        delegate?.cell(cell: FriendTableViewCell, didSelectFollowUser: PFUser)
        self.canFollow = false
    } else {
        delegate?.cell(cell: FriendTableViewCell, didSelectUnfollowUser: PFUser)
        self.canFollow = true
    }
 }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to say `self` which would pass along that specific cell, as opposed to just the generic type.

```
@IBAction func followButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if let canFollow = canFollow, canFollow == true {
        delegate?.cell(cell: self, didSelectFollowUser: PFUser)
        self.canFollow = false
    } else {
        delegate?.cell(cell: self, didSelectUnfollowUser: PFUser)
        self.canFollow = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I feel Dumb.
instead of 

         delegate?.cell(cell: self, didSelectFollowUser: PFUser)

i kept trying

         delegate?.cell(self, didSelectFollowUser: PFUser) 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying you need to provide an object of type `FriendTableViewCell` not the `FriendTableViewCell` type itself.

Just replace `FriendTableViewCell` with `self` in your function:

```
@IBAction func followButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    if let canFollow = canFollow, canFollow == true {
        delegate?.cell(cell: self, didSelectFollowUser: PFUser)
        self.canFollow = false
    } else {
        delegate?.cell(cell: self, didSelectUnfollowUser: PFUser)
        self.canFollow = true
    }
}
```

Comment: That would only work if the IBAction is attached to the whole table view cell, and table view cells don't trigger IBActions directly.

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster says, your delegate function is expecting you to pass in a cell, but you're passing in the CLASS of the cell in the call.

Passing in a cell is a bad idea. You should probably refactor your code to pass in the indexPath of the selected cell, not the cell itself.